# ASP.NET close connection before sending all websocket data to client

Tags: asp.net, azure, websocket

I wrote a simple asp.net websocket handler as a gateway between a remote data processing server and clients.
I tested in my local machine (win8, IIS EXPRESS 8) and everything worked well. But in azure website, ASP.NET closes connection before sending all websocket data to client.

Following is my data transfer code:

```
internal class WebSocketStreamTransfer{

    public WebSocketStreamTransfer(CancellationToken disconnectionToken){
        DisconnectionToken = disconnectionToken;
    }

    private CancellationToken DisconnectionToken{
        get;
        set;
    }

    public async Task AcceptWebSocketConnection(WebSocketContext context) {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        WebSocket websocket = context.WebSocket;
        if (websocket == null)
            throw new SocksOverHttpException("Null websocket");
        using(IConnection conn = ConnectionManagerFactory.ConnectionManager.CreateConnection(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())) {
            try {
                DisconnectionToken.Register(conn.Close);
                TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(null);
                await Task.WhenAny(SendDataToRemoteServer(conn, websocket, DisconnectionToken, tcs), SendDataToClient(conn, websocket, DisconnectionToken, tcs.Task));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Logger.LogException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    internal static async Task SendDataToRemoteServer(IConnection conn, WebSocket websocket, CancellationToken cancelToken, TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs) {
        try {
            ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[ApplicationConfiguration.GetDefaultBufferSize()]);
            while (IsConnected(conn, cancelToken, websocket)) {
                WebSocketReceiveResult result = await websocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, cancelToken);
                if (websocket.State == WebSocketState.Open) {
                    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Binary) {
                        if (result.Count > 0) {
                            if (IsConnected(conn, cancelToken, websocket)) {
                                int numRead = await conn.SendData(buffer.Array, 0, result.Count, cancelToken);
                                if (numRead > 0) {
                                    tcs.TrySetResult(true); // Notify SendDataToClient can continue
                                }else{
                                    Logger.LogError("Client not send enough data for remote connection built");
                                    return;
                                }
                            } else {
                                Logger.LogInformation("SendDataToRemoteServer: Cancel send data to remote server due to connection closed");
                            }
                        } else
                            Logger.LogInformation("Receive empty binary message");
                    } else if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text) {
                        Logger.LogError("Receive unexpected text message");
                        return;
                    } else {
                        Logger.LogInformation("Receive close message");
                        await websocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Close Connection", cancelToken);
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    Logger.LogInformation("SendDataToRemoteServer: WebSocket connection closed by client");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }finally{
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }
    }

    internal static async Task SendDataToClient(IConnection conn, WebSocket websocket, CancellationToken cancelToken, Task connectedTask) {
        await connectedTask;
        while (IsConnected(conn, cancelToken, websocket)) {
            byte[] data = await conn.ReceiveData(cancelToken);
            if (data.Length <= 0) {
                Logger.LogInformation("SendDataToClient: Get empty data from remote server");
                return;
            }
            if (IsConnected(conn, cancelToken, websocket)) {
                await websocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(data), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, cancelToken);
            } else {
                Logger.LogInformation("SendDataToClient: Cancel send data to client due to connection closed");
            }
        }
    }

    internal static bool IsConnected(IConnection conn, CancellationToken cancelToken, WebSocket websocket) {
        bool socketConnected = websocket.State == WebSocketState.Open;
        return socketConnected && conn.Connected && !cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested;
    }
}
```

Problem scenario:

1. SendDataToRemoteServer waiting for client data and client has not data to send yet
2. SendDataToClient receive empty data from remote server, means remote server start closing connection. So finish SendDataToClient
3. AcceptWebSocketConnection finish because `Task.WhenAny(SendDataToRemoteServer(conn, websocket, DisconnectionToken, tcs), SendDataToClient(conn, websocket, DisconnectionToken, tcs.Task))`
4. Expect ASP.NET send all data before close tcp connection but ASP.NET close connection immediately (azure).

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, have you found the cause? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have a sample to show, but basically this breaks the loop and the client never receives a message: while (IsConnected()) { ... await SendAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false); break; } and it happens in Azure only.  I had to add Task.Delay(1000) as a workaround before the "break".

Comment: @Zygimantas I never resolved the problem in Azure website environment. I used  https://github.com/Bobris/Nowin to ran with mono in a docker container, everything works well.

Comment: "Expect ASP.NET send all data before close tcp connection but ASP.NET close connection immediately (azure)." What data needs to be sent before closing? In you descriptions, all data are sent out in step 1-3, and not new data is in, right?

Comment: @Vhao, all data means ASP.NET not only make sure all data sent to network buffer, but also make sure all data packages got ACK response from client. From application logs, all data was passed to SendDataToClient method, but from wireshark, ASP.NET close tcp connection before client received all datas.

Comment: @comphilip In honest, I never saw the issue you said in Azure. In my cases, all data can be sent to and received at the client side. You may need to check your code. Example, add some try/catch in SendDataToClient.  The data transferring may be broken if an exception is raised.

Comment: @Vhao, I admit my case is special. I treat websocket as data transfer bridge of two hosts. I abandonned Azure and swtich to Nowin host a long time ago. I am not sure Azure whether changes underly behavior.

Answer (score 1):

A WebSocket message can be split in different frames. You are not checking if the message is completed. The code for sending information form a WS connection to other should look like this:

```
WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;
do
{
    result = await source.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
    var sendBuffer = new ArraySegment<Byte>(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);

    await target.SendAsync(sendBuffer, result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
}
while (!result.EndOfMessage);
```

You have to check the `EndOfMessage` property, and continue reading while the message is not completed.

It works in your local computer because locally you are no affected by the buffering in the same way, or because the messages you were trying were smaller.

Comment: There is no problem for my code to receive since `SendDataToRemoteServer waiting for client data and client has not data to send yet`.

From wireshark, ASP.NET will auto frame sent data in 4KB size.

Answer (score 0):

`await Task.WhenAny` waits for any task to be completed. does not wait for the SendDataToClient task to be complete when SendDataToRemoteServer  task is completed.

you need change

`await Task.WhenAny(SendDataToRemoteServer(conn, websocket, DisconnectionToken, tcs), SendDataToClient(conn, websocket, DisconnectionToken, tcs.Task));`

to

`await Task.WhenAll(SendDataToRemoteServer(conn, websocket, DisconnectionToken, tcs), SendDataToClient(conn, websocket, DisconnectionToken, tcs.Task));`

With a small sample:

```
async Task t1()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
async Task t2()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
}

Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
await Task.WhenAny(t1(), t2());
watch.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("total milliseconds {0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds); // total milliseconds 1007


Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
await Task.WhenAll(t1(), t2());
watch.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("total milliseconds {0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds); // total milliseconds 2009
```

Comment: It is OK to use WhenAny here because in `SendDataToRemoteServer`, event client sent all data to server, the client will not close the tcp connnection, `SendDataToRemoteServer` will wait until tcp connection closed